# JQuery not detecting appended items

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, append

I have been working for some time on a JQuery web project when I came upon this bug:

`index.html`

```html
<body>
  <div id="target">
    <h1>Will be called</h1>
  </div>
  <button>Add h1</button>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.js"></script>
</body>
```

`index.js`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    $("#target").append(`<h1>` + "Will not be called" + `</h1>`);
  });
});

$("#target h1").click(function() {
  alert("clicked");
})
```

Now the problem here is that if an element is appended, it will not be counted by JQuery even if it is explicitly written to do so.

If you click the hard-written h1, an alert will appear, but if you click the appended one, this will not happen.  In my project, I need both elements to act the same way no matter if they are appended or not.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Delegate the event to a parent element that does exist. Eg: on click of #target if the event.target is a h1 then call the function.

```
$("#target").on("click", "h1", function() {
      alert("clicked");
    })
```

Demo:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    $("#target").append(`<h1>` + "Will also be called" + `</h1>`);
  });
});

//use event delegation
//parent on click of child...
$("#target").on("click", "h1", function() {
  alert("clicked");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <div id="target">
    <h1>Will be called</h1>
  </div>
  <button>Add h1</button>
```

Comment: From the OP question but `$(document).ready(function() {` can just be `$(function() {` which is the recommended form ref: https://api.jquery.com/ready/ and `$("button").click(` might be `$("button").on('click'.`